# Unable to push YUM commands towards cloud VM via Ansible (MacOS)

Tags: python, ansible, dependencies, yum, dnf

Were trying to execute following Ansible playbook:

```html
- name: Create an instance
   hosts: localhost
   gather_facts: no
   vars:
      gcp_project: 
      gcp_cred_kind: serviceaccount
      gcp_cred_file: /users/artyom/my_auth.json
      zone: "us-central1-a"
      region: "us-central1"

   tasks:
   - name: create a disk
     gcp_compute_disk:
         name: 'disk-instance1'
         size_gb: 20
         source_image: 'projects/rocky-linux-cloud/global/images/family/rocky-linux-8'
         zone: "{{ zone }}"
         project: "{{ gcp_project }}"
         auth_kind: "{{ gcp_cred_kind }}"
         service_account_file: "{{ gcp_cred_file }}"
         scopes:
           - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute
         state: present
     register: disk
   - name: create a address
     gcp_compute_address:
         name: 'address-instance1'
         region: "{{ region }}"
         project: "{{ gcp_project }}"
         auth_kind: "{{ gcp_cred_kind }}"
         service_account_file: "{{ gcp_cred_file }}"
         scopes:
           - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute
         state: present
     register: address
   - name: create a instance
     gcp_compute_instance:
         state: present
         name: test-vm12
         machine_type: n1-standard-1
         disks:
           - auto_delete: true
             boot: true
             source: "{{ disk }}"
         network_interfaces:
             - network: null # use default
               access_configs:
                 - name: 'External NAT'
                   nat_ip: "{{ address }}"
                   type: 'ONE_TO_ONE_NAT'
         zone: "{{ zone }}"
         project: "{{ gcp_project }}"
         auth_kind: "{{ gcp_cred_kind }}"
         service_account_file: "{{ gcp_cred_file }}"
         scopes:
           - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute
     register: instance

   - name: Wait for SSH to come up
     wait_for: host={{ address.address }} port=22 delay=10 timeout=60

   - name: Add host to groupname
     add_host: hostname={{ address.address }} groupname=new_instances

   - name: nginx | Install latest nginx
     yum:
        name: nginx
        state: latest
```

Everything works perfect until the last block (yum).
No matter what am I doing to the Python version, this is the error I am getting:

```html
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Could not import the dnf python module using /Users/artyom/opt/anaconda3/bin/python (3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 12:59:45) [Clang 10.0.0 ]). Please install `python3-dnf` or `python2-dnf` package or ensure you have specified the correct ansible_python_interpreter. (attempted ['/usr/libexec/platform-python', '/usr/bin/python3', '/usr/bin/python2', '/usr/bin/python'])", "results": []}
```

I've tried using multiple package managers(e.g. ASDF, PYENV etc.) , python versions, downloading the missing "dnf module" and pointing at it via hosts file, or changing

```html
ansible_python_interpreter
```

To auto, auto_legacy, pointing at python location, at exactly were previously downloaded python-dnf modules stores etc. etc.

I am struggling with that issue already for 2 weeks, all the other SOF and other sites googling does not resolve the issue by any kind.

At the given moment I am using Python via Anaconda.

```html
python - V output is:
Python 3.8.8
```

Also tried adding, "use_backend="(all of the possible versions of it).

After modifying access right to the hosts file and changing it contents, I am getting this:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/artyom/opt/anaconda3/bin/ansible-playbook", line 62, in import ansible.constants as C File "/Users/artyom/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible/constants.py", line 181, in config = ConfigManager() File "/Users/artyom/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible/config/manager.py", line 302, in init self._config_file = find_ini_config_file(self.WARNINGS) File "/Users/artyom/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible/config/manager.py", line 244, in find_ini_config_file potential_paths.append(unfrackpath("~/.ansible.cfg", follow=False)) File "/Users/artyom/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible/utils/path.py", line 50, in unfrackpath b_basedir = to_bytes(os.getcwd(), errors='surrogate_or_strict') PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no answers, I am attaching list of steps in order to resolve the issue.

SSH keys should be imported from execute machine into GCP VM.

Hosts file:

---

```
[a]
IP of VM
```

Playbook to execute YUM:

```
---
 - name: Create IP address
   become: yes
   hosts: a
   gather_facts: no

   vars:
    service_account_file: /my_auth.json
    project: your_project_id
    auth_kind: serviceaccount
    scopes:
      - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute

   tasks:

    - name: Update
      shell: "yum install mc -y"
```

Ansible.cfg:

```
[inventory]
enable_plugins = gcp_compute, yaml, ini
```

N.B. This should be added either at config or at playbook command:

```
-e 'ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/libexec/platform-python'
```